# Unity ArgumentOutOfRangeException when loading Collaborate history

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been unity collab for sometime and everything was smooth. However this morning, when trying to load my teams' changes from collab's history I got this weird Exception.

"ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
Parameter name: t
System.DateTime.op_Addition (System.DateTime d, System.TimeSpan t) (at <9577ac7a62ef43179789031239ba8798>:0)
"
This error appears on my Console windows as soon as I click on the History button from Colab, and it's as is the history crashed and didn't load..
Has anyone gone through this ?

[image: Screenshot of the error.]

Full logs:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
Parameter name: t
System.DateTime.op_Addition (System.DateTime d, System.TimeSpan t) (at <9577ac7a62ef43179789031239ba8798>:0)
System.DateTimeOffset.op_Addition (System.DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset, System.TimeSpan timeSpan) (at <9577ac7a62ef43179789031239ba8798>:0)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Utilities.TimeStamp.GetElapsedTime (System.DateTimeOffset dateTime) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Utilities/TimeStamp.cs:62)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Utilities.TimeStamp.GetTimeStamp (System.DateTimeOffset dateTime) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Utilities/TimeStamp.cs:33)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Views.HistoryTabPageView.CreateHistoryEntry (Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Models.Structures.IHistoryEntry entry, System.Boolean expanded) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Views/HistoryTabPageView.cs:189)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Views.HistoryTabPageView.SetHistoryList (System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] list) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Views/HistoryTabPageView.cs:95) Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Presenters.HistoryPresenter.OnHistoryListReceived (System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] list) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Presenters/HistoryPresenter.cs:123)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Models.HistoryModel.OnReceivedHistoryPage (System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] list) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Models/HistoryModel.cs:98) Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Models.Providers.Collab.RequestHistoryPage (System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 pageSize, System.Action`1[T] callback) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Models/Providers/Collab.cs:531)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Models.HistoryModel.RequestPageOfRevisions (System.Int32 pageSize) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Models/HistoryModel.cs:126)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Presenters.HistoryPresenter.PopulateInitialData () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Presenters/HistoryPresenter.cs:93)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Presenters.HistoryPresenter.Start () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Presenters/HistoryPresenter.cs:48)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Views.HistoryTabPageView.SetActive () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Views/HistoryTabPageView.cs:222)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Components.TabPageComponent.SetActive (System.Boolean active) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Components/TabPageComponent.cs:21)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Components.TabView.SwitchTabInternal (System.Int32 index) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Components/TabView.cs:138)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Components.TabView+<>c__DisplayClass17_0.b__0 () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Components/TabView.cs:87)
Unity.Cloud.Collaborate.Components.TextButton.OnClick () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.3.9/Editor/Components/TextButton.cs:32)
UnityEngine.UIElements.Clickable.Invoke (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.Clickable.ProcessUpEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.Vector2 localPosition, System.Int32 pointerId) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.Clickable.OnMouseUp (UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseUpEvent evt) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventCallbackFunctor`1[TEventType].Invoke (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventCallbackRegistry.InvokeCallbacks (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy.DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel, System.Boolean imguiEventIsInitiallyUsed) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEventQueue () (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.OpenGate () (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate.Dispose () (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel, UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode dispatchMode) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel.SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase e, UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode dispatchMode) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel panel) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr, System.Boolean& eventHandled) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at :0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration+<>c.<.cctor>b__1_2 (System.Int32 i, System.IntPtr ptr) (at :0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr, System.Boolean& result) (at <2500dd078a544a69b6c923861af6cd15>:0)

Comment: Add the script where this line is runing please. Seems like you are making some addition method on a DateTime object passing an out of range argument.

Comment: there is no where in my script any reference to DateTime, I will add the full logs

Answer (score 0):

Follow up:
I didn't technically solve the problem but the bug stopped happening. I basically edited the Assets directory, (nothing fancy, just created a new folder) and reloaded the Collaborate service. That fixed it smh.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today. The cause was an incorrect system time (I switched timezone, due to an improperly configured dual-boot setup).

In particular, this might be caused when rendering the dialogs "x minutes ago", relative to current time in the new Collab's history tab, for the edits.

The fix: updated my system time to correct time zone.

The original poster might have faced the issue due to a similar reason, and not any file in their own project.